# Omitting Which / That in a Sentence

Tags: relative-clauses, syntactic-analysis

The following sentence is from Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. I'm wondering if it's correct and what it means:

> “Give me a couple of dates are good for you.”

Shouldn't it be “Give me a couple of dates that/which are good for you.”

[image]

Comment: That source seems dubious -- it's apparently unrelated to OU.

Comment: @Kris https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/ -- note the OUP logo at the bottom of the page. User249253, It would be *really* helpful if you could link to the definition as well as include the words themselves.

Comment: It's wrong. The relativized element ("that/which") is subject of the relative clause and therefore obligatory. Note that strictly speaking, "that" is not a relativized element, but just a subordinator. Neverthless, "that"/ "which" are not omissible.

Comment: OP, you could @OUPELTGlobal Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a mistake in the "Extra examples" listed for the word *[date](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/date_1).*

You are correct: it's necessary to include the word "that" or "which" before "are" in a sentence like this.

Comment: By the way, is the rule as simple as that you can omit the relative pronoun when it's an object as opposed to a subject? "Give me a couple of dates (that) I can pencil in." Is the subject/object difference the difference?

Comment: @Zebrafish: It is, except for the complication that some modern linguists don't classify "that" as a relative pronoun, but as a "relativizer".

Comment: In "The person whom I met is very tall", does the fact that you can remove the "whom" according to this relative pronoun omission rule maybe strengthen the point you made about "whom" being possibly correct here as opposed to "who"? As I understand it according to that OLO article "whom" is wrong.

Comment: @Zebrafish: Janus Bahs Jacquet left some comments suggesting a connection like that, but the fact that "who(m)" can be omitted in phrases like "The person (who(m)) I thought was there" doesn't *necessarily* support my point in that other answer. Prescriptivists can just say that the correct rule is "you cannot omit a wh-word when it is the subject **of the relative clause**" (and also, you cannot omit *that* when the relative clause has a gap in subject position).

Comment: @Zebrafish: In fact, "whom" is correct in  "The person whom I met is very tall" even from a prescriptivist point of view, because the structure of that sentence is  "[The person [whom I met] is very tall]". The relative pronoun is the direct object of the verb *met.* So in my last comment, I changed the example from that sentence to the phrase "The person [(who(m)) I thought was there]".

Comment: That should have been edited into the post, rather.

Comment: @sumelic, I asked another question this morning. Would you please write your opinion about it?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482419/using-the-progressive-form-of-be-for-a-state-of-the-mind-and-lately-in-present-c

Answer (score -1):

Rephrase that sentence as:

Kindly schedule the meeting on any of the following dates:
 - Date 1
 - Date 2
 - Date 3

We could discuss about "topic of interest" after lunch/before lunch at "meeting place". Please share your calendar for the same.

Comment: That's not the question, though.