# 'that make me' or 'which make me' and when to omit 'that'

Tags: grammar, word-choice, relative-clauses

Should I use 'that' or 'which' in the following sentence?

> My teaching experience and technical background are not the only factors **which/that** make me a suitable applicant.

Additionally, how do I know when to omit 'that' from a sentence? For instance, consider these sentences:

> It was during those 2 years **that** I began comprehending the sophistication of techniques employed in the industry.

> It was two years of my life **that** I enjoyed thoroughly.

> I am confident **that** I can make a positive contribution to your organisation.

In which of the above should I omit the word and how do I know when to do so?

Thanks

Comment: 1 requires that. 2. that cannot be omitted. 3. _ditto_ 4. _that_ is optional

Comment: @user405662 Why does the first sentence require *that* and not *which*?
Also, is the third sentence correct?

Comment: I consider that you could use either _which_ or _that_ - or simply _making me_. You _should_ not omit the word from any of the three sentences; you _could_ omit it from the third.

Comment: rjaditya: In nutshell, if you are merely providing additional info, use _which_; if, however, the following clause is essential to the meaning of the sentence, use _that_. That said, the rule isn't strictly observed and the two are often used interchangeably.

Comment: I would strongly discourage you from omitting *that* in the sentence *"It was during ..."* , because the phrase that follows *that* is quite long. I don't think this is a grammatical issue, though, but a stylistic one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use “that” and when to use “which”, especially in relative clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which-especially-in-relative-clauses) Or this? [Omitting 'which' or 'that' in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482244/omitting-which-that-in-a-sentence)

Comment: @Peter Shor: _That_ is necessitated there more by grammatical considerations than stylistic, right? Could you please explain _why_ not if you think otherwise?

Comment: @user405662: I think the OP's second sentence sounds lot better with *that* in it, but I don't find anything wrong with *"It was during those years I lost my way,"* where the relative clause is a lot shorter. These are grammatically the same (if you don't think so, tell me why). And the general rule for when you can drop *that* – when it's not the subject of the relative clause – is satisfied by both of these sentences.

Answer (score 1):

"My teaching... are not the only factors which/that make me a suitable applicant." => **'which' and 'that'** are **relative pronouns** (they stand for 'factors'). Since they are the **subjects** of the verb 'make', **you cannot omit them**. Both are correct. 'Which' is more formal.

In sentences 2, 3, 4, **'that'** – whether it's a relative pronoun or a relative conjunction – is  **not the subject** of the verb that follows. Y**ou can omit 'that'**, if you like... Omitting 'that' will make your sentence slightly more informal.